# In Aws Lex - using lambda can we change the slot values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

say for example there is a non-required slot present in intent and value I entered on Lex is A and then I need to change the value of slot to B.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this through the use of your custom Lambda function.

My suggestion would be to use the `sessionAttributes` to store the modified slot values. Use your Lambda function to change the slot's raw value and then save this to the `sessionAttributes`.

Ensure that you set these `sessionAttributes` correctly on the response from the Lambda function.

Please refer to the developer guide for the full schemas of the request and response formats.

[Lambda Function Input Event and Response Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

If you want to edit the raw value, you can do so as well. The below is a snippet from a Python Lambda function that I have supporting a V1 Lex bot:

```
if first_name is not None:
  originalValue = event['currentIntent']['slotDetails']['firstName']['originalValue']
  originalValue = originalValue.replace("-"," ")
  slot_values["firstName"] = originalValue
```

I then include the modifed `slot_values` in the response to Lex:

```
 'dialogAction': {
        'type': 'ElicitSlot',
        'intentName': ...,
        'slots': slot_values,
        'slotToElicit': ...,
        'message': ...
    }
```

You can modify the response to perform your desired dialog action by setting the correct value for `type`.

Comment: How can i change raw value, i tried setting something like : event["sessionState]["intent"]["slot"] = value but it did not work

Comment: I've updated the original answer to include a code snippet that will hopefully provide more clarity.

Comment: Nothing changed after i tried this